# git submodule to import a folder

Tags: python, git, git-submodules

How can we copy shared folder using git submodule ?Actually the requirement is that the shared folder should be present inside one folder out of the 4 folders present inside the repo in github. But when we clone the repo , the shared folder should be copied in all the 3 other folders from the one folder where shared folder is present … All the 4 folders are inside one repo only.. The requirement is to use a particular folder in all the DM folders in the project using git submodules .. Currently we are using the shared inside all the folders of the project .. Now we want to keep it in one folder where other folders can access it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give an example of what it currently looks like and what you want it to look like, because your description and use of "others" is quite confusing. And what do you mean by "shared folder"? That's not a thing in git terminology, as far as I'm aware. Also what are DM folders? And how is this related to Python?